# Box constraints with BFGS algorithm

Tags: optimization, data-transformation

I've been a long time adept of the Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno algorithm (BFGS), which I trusted to be a pretty efficient local optimisation technique. And indeed it is.

The problem I usually face however is when I need to account for box constraints, say $x \in [a,b]$.

Since BFGS cannot handle these "natively" I usually work on a transformed unconstrained problem by defining $y \in \Bbb{R}$ related to $x \in [a,b]$ through a one-to-one monotonic mapping
\begin{align}
g &: [a,b] \to \Bbb{R} \\
  &: x \to y = g(x) = \tan\left( \frac{(x-a)\pi}{b-a} - \frac{\pi}{2} \right)
\end{align}
The problem 
$$ \hat{x} = \underset{{x \in [a,b]}}{\text{argmin}}\,\,\, f(x) $$
then becomes equivalent to solving
\begin{gather}
\hat{y} = \underset{{y \in \Bbb{R}}}{\text{argmin}}\,\,\,  \tilde{f}(y) \\
\tilde{f}(y) := f(g^{-1}(y)) 
\end{gather}
When computing the gradients of the above transformed cost function one gets
$$ \frac{\partial \tilde{f}}{\partial y} = f'(g^{-1}(y)) \frac{\partial g^{-1}}{\partial y}(y) $$
where 
\begin{align}
g^{-1}(y) &= a + \frac{b-a}{\pi} \left(\text{atan}(y) + \pi/2 \right) \\
\frac{\partial g^{-1}}{\partial y}(y) &= \frac{b-a}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+y^2}
\end{align}

One problem I see is that when we reach the bounds of the optimisation domain ($x \to a$ or $x \to b$ hence $y \to \mp \infty$), the optimiser gets stuck and cannot get out. This is because the Jacobian $\partial x/\partial y$ above then becomes zero which means that the line search direction in at iteration $k$ given by
$$ p_k = -H_k^{-1} G_k $$ 
where $H_k$ is the (approximated) Hessian and $G_k$ the gradient of the function $\tilde{f}(y)$ inherits of the zero-valued components of the Jacobian via the chain rule. For multivariate non-linear optimisation problem this can and will happen quite frequently.

If I am to stick with the BFGS algorithm, can some of you provide me with some tricks to avoid that or some lessons you've learned to control this phenomenon? Do I necessarily have to go through penalisation of some kind or should I simply changed my mapping which is indeed numerically ill-defined as $x$ reaches its bounds (gradient hugely increases when I get close to the bounds)?

Thanks a lot and sorry if this has already been discussed over this site, can't seem to get the info.

Comment: I will also like to know if there is a solution to this.

Comment: Do your objective functions typically return "reasonable" values for $x$ outside of $[a,b]$, in which case the constraints are ones of plausibility or known physical relationships, or is there a computational failure that occurs?

Comment: Say that the *definition domain* of the function is $x \in [a,b]$. I've noticed there is a '-B' version of the BFGS algorithm which a priori handles box constraints. I'm having a look at it but as far as my question is concerned I would like to know if there are any fixes sticking with the traditional BFGS